# How to access the blog index.php when home.php is used?

Tags: wordpress

I'm sure there's a simple solution to this, but I find a solution.

I have homepage.php created to display some content, then I have index.php created to display a blogroll and single.php created for single blog posts - Now how do I access index.php?? I can view the individual posts by either typing in the title in the URL or click on the "view post" button in admin, but what about the actually index.php where the list of my blogs sit??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nvm, I just had to create the pages, assign the templates accordingly, and set the frontpage and blog in the Reading section of Settings. Hope this is helpful to someone else.